# Custom List sorting

Tags: groovy

Hi I have a list which contains elements `[daily,monthly,weekly]` or `[monthly,weekly,daily]` or `[weekly,daily]`

I need to sort the list in such a way that

```
[daily,monthly,weekly] == [daily,monthly,weekly]

[monthly, weekly, daily] == [daily, monthly, weekly]

[weekly, daily] == [daily, weekly]
```

Can some one please help me in this

Comment: Can you give examples of the lists you have?  What is `daily`?  A String?  An object with a specific class?  It's really hard to see what you mean... Also, in what way is this connected to Grails?

Comment: Hi Tim these are just strings

Comment: Cool, then my answer below should work

Comment: ok but my question is the input may be any combination of daily m0nthly weekly). so i can not keep on writing all the combinations for assert right.

Comment: The assert is to show you it works... I don't get what you mean...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you mean that you have a list of Strings, then this should work:

```
customSorter = { 
  [ 'daily', 'monthly', 'weekly' ].indexOf( it )
}

assert [ 'daily', 'monthly', 'weekly' ].sort( customSorter ) == [ 'daily', 'monthly', 'weekly' ]
assert [ 'monthly', 'weekly', 'daily' ].sort( customSorter ) == [ 'daily', 'monthly', 'weekly' ]
assert [ 'weekly', 'daily' ].sort( customSorter ) == [ 'daily', 'weekly' ]
```

Or you could do this (to avoid repeatedly creating a List)

```
customSorter = { a, b, order=['daily','monthly','weekly'] ->
  order.indexOf( a ) <=> order.indexOf( b )
}
```

Comment: I like it, though it's rather inefficient to create a whole new `ArrayList` every time you call the closure.  Creating it once with a `def values = ['daily', 'weekly', 'monthly'] ; def customSorter = { values.indexOf(it) }` would be better.

Comment: @IanRoberts Good point.. Added a third option to my answer with a default parameter ;-)