# Custom Sort Groovy JSONArray - Custom Values First, Then Alphabetical

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, grails, groovy

I have a static list of values that is in a JSONArray. Here is my example array:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray()

json = ["B", "E", "C", "Z", "A", "X", "F", "H"]
```

I need to sort this json array in a custom way. I need to put "E" first, "F" second, and then sort the rest by alphabetical order.

I want my end result to be this:

```
json = ["E", "F", "A", "B", "C", "H", X", "Z"]
```

Groovy has the basic sort functionality that I can sort alphabetically or reverse alphabetically using:

```
json.sort()
```

or

```
json.reverse()
```

I'm looking for an easy way to do a custom sort.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623728/custom-list-sorting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210705/groovy-advance-sort/28212959#28212959

Answer (score 1):

in my 5-min experiment I used weights:

```
def json = ["B", "E", "C", "Z", "A", "X", "F", "H"]
def weights = [ E:10, F:9 ]

json.sort{
  it.charAt( 0 ) - ( weights[ it ] ?: 0 )
}

assert '[E, F, A, B, C, H, X, Z]' == json.toString()
```

you might want to include some error checking

Answer (score 0):

You can use closures if you define your own sort method, but what you're actually asking for is some array splitting with a little normal sorting.

```
json.findAll{it = 'E'} + json.findAll{it = 'F'} + json.findAll{!(it in ['E', 'F'])}.sort()
```

If you're worried about the efficiency of looping through your json 3 times you can iterate through your json once, adding it to different arrays as you go.

The below example is a little fancier. The inject method will iterate over a collection, passing a value between each iteration (in our case a list of 3 lists. The first list will hold our E's, the second our F's, and the 3rd for everything else. After sorting our catchall list we use .flatten() to transform the 3 lists back into one list.

```
List organizedList = json.inject([[],[],[]]) {List<List> result, String jsonValue ->
    select(jsonValue) {
        case 'E':
            result.get(0).add(jsonValue) // Could have just added 'E' but I like symmetry
            break;
        case 'F':
            result.get(1).add(jsonValue)
            break;
        default:
            result.get(2).add(jsonValue)
    }
    return result // Gets passed to each iteration over json
}
organizedList.get(2).sort() // sort on a list modifies the original list 
organizedList.flatten()
```

It's also possible using sort with a closure where you define your own sorting; but as you can see, it doesn't flow quite as easily.

```
json.sort {String a, String b ->  
    if (a = b) return 0 // For efficiency's sake

    def letterFirst = {String priority -> // Closure to help sort against a hardcoded value
        if (a = priority) return 1
        if (b = priority) return -1    
        return 0
    }

    def toReturn = letterFirst('E')
    if (!toReturn) toReturn = letterFirst('F') // groovy evaluates 0 as false
    if (!toReturn) toReturn = a <=> b
    return toReturn 
}
```